# Type of interface iOS interface used in Stripes iOS App

Tags: ios, user-interface

I have been building out a iOS app and would like to create the kind of view that you can see here on the stripe app.

Video:https://stripe.com/img/dashboard_iphone/screencast.mp4

at 0:06 seconds you can see that as you swipe up the table view below comes into view and the graph at the top dissappears.

I see this design in alot of apps, but not sure if there is a common pattern for creating it with xCode and the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just animate it to the bottom of graph view. Here is a simple example:

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
frame.origin.y = graphView.frame.origin.y + graphView.bounds.size.height;
frame.size.height = self.tableView.superview.bounds.size.height - frame.origin.y;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
} completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Have you got any good resources on this kind of pattern or was it just learnt knowledge.

Comment: I think there is no pattern for this kind of things. It is just how UIView animation works and how people use it. If you are struggling with how to start and learn correct way of using tools - check http://www.raywenderlich.com/, it has wonderful tutorials.

Comment: Where should I be applying this code? The UITableViewController or somehwere else?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in UITableViewController.

Comment: Any idea how you would do this in Swift?

Comment: `var frame = tableView.frame
        frame.origin.y = graphView.frame.maxY
        frame.size.height = tableView.bounds.height - frame.origin.y
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: .BeginFromCurrentState, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.frame = frame
            }, completion: nil)`

Comment: This is great but when I try and run this code it doesnt work, I have a container view which contains my table view and it seems that the container view doesn't have a frame property for some reason

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correct you want to have table view below graphs and then when user swipes you want table view to overlay graphs, right?

If yes, then you need to create UITableView, make sure it is on top of graph view, and animate a change of tableView.frame.origin.y and tableView.frame.size.height.

Comment: That sounds exactly right is there a way though of stopping it from sliding all the way off the bottom and giving it a fixed stopping point.